# Aspose dependency not working with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, aspose-cells

I am trying to add Aspose cells dependency in gradle but I am not able to make it work .
Attaching the gradle file and the error in terminal for the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, http access has been disabled now due to security reasons. Our repository URL is `https://repository.aspose.com/repo/` which is only accessible through Maven or Gradle clients. You can explore our repository through https://repository.aspose.com/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/repo.

For example, you may update your maven configurations as below:

```
....
<repositories>

      <repository>

          <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>

          <name>Aspose Java API</name>

          <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>

   </repository>

</repositories>
```

For complete reference see the [document](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/installation/) on how to install Aspose.Cells for Java from Maven Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Download specified version jar from https://repository.aspose.com/repo/com/aspose/aspose-cells/
and place it in dependency path

And use below line in build.gradle for including in dependency
compile(group: 'com.aspose', name: 'aspose-cells', version: '22.10')